# Parsing MIME mail type

Tags: c#, asp.net, mime-types, mime

After lots of efforts I created my own mail parser. Now successfully able to parse and display emails. But few mails especially sent from apple or Iphone appear like this after parsing. I have no idea why this is happening. Please help.

=D8=AA=D9=88=D8= =A7=D8=AC=D9=87=D9=86=D9=8A =D9=85=D8=B4=D9=83=D9=84=D8=A9 =D8=A5=D8=B4=D8= =A7=D8=B1=D8=A9 =D9=84=D9=84=D9=83=D8=B1=D8=AA =D8=B1=D9=82=D9=85 410814189= 68 =D8=B9=D9=84=D9=85=D8=A7=D9=8B =D8=A8=D8=A3=D9=86 =D8=A5=D8=B4=D8=

Comment: any final solution with full source code ?

Comment: I just managed to create one for my need. I was not able to find one which can handle all mail types.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you mail parser does not handle decoding of Quoted Printable content.

I imagine that if you looked at the headers, you'd find a header like this:

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

I've written several email clients and multiple mime parsers and am currently working on writing a new mime parser in C# (the others were in C) called MimeKit here: http://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit. This may be of interest to you...

I've got a filterable stream class that you can add a QuotedPrintableDecoder to (which I've also implemented), then pass your data through that to decode it. Or you could just pass it through the QuotedPrintableDecoder directly, depending on whatever is easiest for you.

Example usage:

```
var decoder = new QuotedPrintableDecoder ();
var output = new byte[decoder.EstimateOutputLength (input.Length)];
var outputLength = decoder.Decode (input, 0, input.Length, output);

// convert the output into a string displayable to the user...
var text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString (output, 0, outputLength);
```

Obviously you'd use the proper System.Text.Encoding for the content (by looking at the "charset" parameter in the Content-Type header) instead of blindly using System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.